# insert php plugins not working Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

In my projects, there are many links of forms, certificates. If suppose client want to migrate the project from one domain to another, automatically links should be updated. For that purpose, I have used [Insert php](https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php/) plugin in wordpress. Also I have activated that plugin as per the given instructions. Unfortunately shortcode is also displaying in frontend. How should i get homeurl in frontend using this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use this plugin. I think enabling PHP in WordPress content is a high security risk. If the only thing you need is the home url, we you don't user relative paths? Then you are using always the right URL.

If that is not an option, consider creating a shortcode for replacing it with the home url.

```
//[home_url]
function home_url_shortcode( $atts ){
    return home_url();
}

add_shortcode( 'home_url', 'home_url_shortcode' );
```

Place this in your themes functions.php and use it with [home_url]

Besides the solution of the above. If you migrate a WordPress project you should run a search/replace on the database for the old and the new domain. WordPress uses the full domain on multiple occasions. So this is not a solid solution.

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/
- https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/